# Apply CSS to data within TD but not to the TD. Need to up baseline of text in every TD. Maby text-atribute selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to up text but if i apply class to TD or TR in IE, Opera and Chrome all cell goes up (background and border and text in cell).
Please look example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <style>
  .myClass  td{
      position:relative;
      top:-8px;
      color:blue;
      }

  .myClass {
      position:relative;
      top:-8px;
      color:blue;
      } 
td { border: red solid 2px ;}   
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table  width="384" height="89" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" bgcolor="#cccccc">
    <tr >
      <td width="109" bgcolor="#FFCC00">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="255" bgcolor="#00CCFF" class="myClass">this TD have class=&quot;.myClass&quot;</td>
</tr>
<tr  class="myClass">
      <td bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">this TR have class=&quot;.myClass&quot;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#666666">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><span class="myClass">this text within span-tags (.myClass)</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Firefox don`t affect if is applied to tr_or_td, affect only to text with span-tag.

Every browsers work correct if in every TD of a row place text within

```
<span class="tdclass"> mytext in span-tag </span>
```

QUESTIONS) :

1. Is there some css structure to assign style only to data within TD but not to this TD

   ```
   tr.myclass TD {}
   ```

in IE, Opera, Chrome applies to all cell, in Firefox don`t work at all.

1. Is there some css selector of TEXT - I mean for example:

   ```
   .myclass > b
   ```

   will be applied when in tag with .myclass we have b-tag

   maby some word like EVERY_TEXT - may be such selector, for example:

   ```
   .myclass > EVERY_TEXT {}
   ```
2. can anybody suggest another workable way to up text in all cells of table without span in every cell, and without .js

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You cannot apply a style to the content inside the cell without it being applied to the cell itself. For this you will need to wrap the content inside a `span`, `div`, or `p` tag and then style them appropriately. Unfortunately that is the only way to do that with HTML and CSS. Also you should not use `bgcolor` and instead have the colours defined in the stylesheet for the table cells.

Answer (score 1):

Use an asterisk to select all elements in that section of the DOM, e.g.

```
​<div ​​​​class="one">
    testing <br/>
    <span> Test </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​


.one * {
    color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle here, if you need to check it](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7mE/)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn`t helps.

look it in IE, Opera or Chrome:

Comment: Have tested it in chrome, safari, opera, firefox, all of them work.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn`t helps with "position:relative", "top:-8px" - this parameters applies to bot TD and text within, parameter in your style is "color" it applies only to font-color - NOT LIKE parameter POSITON.

Comment: everything I try works, and I can barely make out what you're trying to say... The `position` property works for *both* absolute *and* relative. [Fiddle for absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7mE/1/), and [Fiddle for relative](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z7mE/2/). If this isn't what you're looking for, please specify what you need different, because from what I can tell this is what the original question was asking for

Comment: Sorry for mistakes in my English text).

in ie, opera, Chrome
css-attribute "position" applies to TD (cell) and text within TD (cell) - in this case the cell with text goes up - BUT I NEED ONLY THE TEXT GOES UP !!!

PLEASE
1. COPY CODE FROM THE FIRST TOPIC,
2. SAVE AS HTML
3. OPEN IN   • FIREFOX  
and   
• OPERA  or  • CHROME  or  • IE
4. see the differences.

AND YOU`LL UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM :) !

Answer (score 0):

You could add a span tag around the content in the TD cell and apply CSS to the span.

```
<td>
    <span class="styled_cell_content">Content</span>
</td>
```

Comment: I know). But the table have a lot of cells, that need such span`s. 
Ive asked for way that allow to take a goal with one or two css rules and one-two-three class-declarations.

Comment: If you are just trying to position the text you could use vertical-align. It, for the most part, only applies to text.

Comment: I use vertical-align:top and position:relative and top:-2px 

but only vertical-align:top   it is not enought (

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a negative padding?

```
.myClass,
.myClass td {
    color:blue;
    padding-top: -8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for the answer to this, you need to specifically set the border at the td (and th) level - in IE this takes precedence over the color set on the whole element.  For example, add this to your css, now IE will use this to style the border and the color set on td won't change it!

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```